# jQuery Form Plugin : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.....No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-forms-plugin

I developed a file manager based on [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) plugin

Recently, i find myself in front of this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.****.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://****.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This don't happen before. It doesn't happen with all files, but in my last case happens with an .zip file (a zip file with images , 50MB , but i think this isn't important).

I have read several questions on SO about a similar problem, but not when loading a file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have misinterpreted the problem. I doubt it has anything to do with the size of the file.

Look at the error message:

`cannot load http://www.test.com/` and `'http://test.com' not allowed access`.

You're changing the site you are loading in your browser from `www.test.com` to `test.com` and are making it a cross-origin request in the process.

- Use relative URLs in your code
- Pick one hostname to host your site on
- Redirect requests from the other hostname to it

Comment: The file manager is here: test.com, and upload files here: test.com

Comment: @WhiteLine — According to the error message it is on `test.com` and trying to upload to `www.test.com`

Comment: The php script for upload responds with `Status Code:302 Found` . The script does not seem to be called

Comment: @WhiteLine — This does not surprise me. I refer you back to my answer for the solution.

Comment: what I don't understand is why it does not happen with all files

Comment: Presumably because sometimes you are testing on `www.test.com` and sometimes you are testing on `test.com`. See the very first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I have realized that the problem is not related to the files, but i can not figure out what could be the problem. I also tried the famous `https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload` library  and there is the same problem, and certainly in this library there are no problems

Comment: "I have realized that the problem is not related to the files" — That's what the very first paragraph of my answer says.

Comment: "but i can not figure out what could be the problem" — My answer tells you what the problem is, and what the solution is.

Comment: the filemanger works on my local machine and also on another my web site , and when upload it on the second web site there is the problem , so the problem is not the code of the filemanager , but on some configuration of the server , in my opinion

Comment: @WhiteLine — Correct. I told you, in the answer, what that configuration problem is too. You are hosting the website on two different hostnames (and then switching between them with your browser).

Comment: so the fact that the website is accessible with www and without www might be a problem?

Comment: As I said in the answer, it is **the** problem.

Comment: For information : i move the filemanger to a subdomain and all the problems are gone, the problem was most likely wordpress.

Comment: Wordpress is not the problem. The problem was that you were hosting it on two different origins and mixing it. You could have moved to just `www`. You could have moved to just *no* `www`. Moving to just `something-else` is also an option, but probably overkill.