# JQuery / AJAX: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following script (simplfied) that grabs some data from a local php file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var current_date = "x=y";

  $.ajax
  ({ 
    url: 'work/get_cal.php',
    type: 'post',
    data : current_date,
    async: false,
    success: function(result)
    {
      alert('never gets this far');
    }
  });

});
```

However I get a cross domain error, even though everything is on the same server.  Has anyone had this issue before?

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/work/get_cal.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Comment: Test it in Chrome, that gives better error messages and tells you about all the origins involved.

Comment: Examine the Network tab of your developer tools. Do you see the request and response? Are they what you expect? (Most importantly, do you get a 3xx redirect to a different origin?)

Comment: Use jsonp as datatype. Not json. jsonp is for cross origin communications

Comment: just a thought on `async: false,` do you really need this?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha — The point of the question is that it shouldn't be cross origin. JSONP is a horribly hack anyway, we now have CORS which is a much better solution to allowing cross-origin requests.

Comment: I suppose you need to test your code in localhost if you're not ! and make sure test it in chrome

Comment: Are you sure you are using relative paths like in your example code and not absolute paths with `http://`? If absolute paths, then make sure that current url and your request are at the same domain level (both using `www.` or both not using `www.`).

Comment: Check if you are on https and trying to call Http url, or vise versa

Comment: @Uzbekjon you are correct, the current URL wasn't using www but the request was.  This was the problem, thanks everyone!

Comment: Added it as an answer for future googlers.

Comment: It seems that the code in the question isn't actually the code being asked about, and that the problem was caused by a typo. This question really should just be closed (possibly as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887480/jquery-form-plugin-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-www-no-access-contro)) and deleted.

Comment: @Quentin "However I get a cross domain error, even though everything is on the same server. Has anyone had this issue before?

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resourc...`" The code may not be relevant but the question is clear and concise... If you think this is not a correct question, then why are you down-voting selective answers and not the question itself????

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to **get_cal.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This will allow to make `Cross-Origin` Request.

Comment: The question is asking why they are getting a cross-origin error when they are trying to make a same origin request. They aren't asking how to disable cross-origin security.

Answer (score -1):

From comments to the original question for future Googlers.

The code used absolute paths and ended up in different domain "level" when the page was accessed with `www` and the script was requesting without `www`. This caused CORS problem.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct answer as OP has confirmed!

Answer (score -1):

*Same Origin Policy* permits running scripts in a browser and allows making requests to pages on with the **SAME** *URI Scheme*, *hostname* and *port number*. This is implemented for security within most of the browsers.

I personally use Chrome with *Web Security* Disabled during testing. Use the **--disable-web-security** parameter to enable this in your Chrome.

I strongly advice creating a seperate *shortcut* for development & testing purposes and **NOT** to use this option for your regular browsing...

`"C:\<path_to_chrome_folder>\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

`--user-data-dir` is used to store the session details and other browser data, thus keeping is separate from your regular browsing data.

`--disable-web-security` disables the security and thus the *Same Origin Policy* warning.

Hope this helps...!

Comment: This does not answer the question (which is asking why they are getting a cross-origin error for a same origin request)

Comment: This answers why the error occurs and how to bypass it only for Dev & Test purposes... Similar response has been given by Deepak Adhikar without any explanations on the error, why didnt you voted down his answer as well???